How to copy releases from a fork or create one and upload assets with an existing action?
I want to copy the release from the original repo to this fork: https://github.com/QuadraAI/whichcam
But it seems like I cannot modify the "write" rights in the action settings even if I'm the owner of the main repository.
Do you guys have any idea on how I could do that, preferably not copying files one by one

You would have to use GitHub API for managing releases
You will need two PAT tokens: one for the original repo and one for the fork.
You could use GitHub CLI to simplify writing API requests in bash.

I made a bash script for that: https://github.com/MidKnightXI/synchronize
